# Garbled text in OSX Java text field

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtextfield

When I edit text in a `JTextField` in my Swing application on OSX, the text gets garbled. It's most pronounced when I insert or delete characters but there are artifacts just when moving the cursor around. The data is fine, but the UI rendering is not.

[image: Garbled text in OSX Java text input]

What causes this and how can I fix it?

I'm using `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, as in this sample program. Type in some text and move the cursor around with the arrow keys to observe the weirdness.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextFieldDisplay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
    }
}

class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
        try  {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("AquaLookAndFeel is not supported on your platform.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(innerPanel);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(innerPanel);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));

        innerPanel.add(textField);
        pack();
    }
}
```

I noticed as I was writing the SSCCE that the display issues seemed to crop up after I added the `JScrollPane`.

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm using Apple Java version `1.6.0_51` with a retina display.

Comment: Consider creating and posting a [minimal test program](http://sscce.org) also known as an sscce that we can run, test, modify, and correct.

Comment: Please post a small code sample that demonstrates the issue (A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) - otherwise all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: what look and feel are you using??

Comment: @BrianRoach Will update in a few minutes. Full code [here](https://github.com/cbednarski/hostess/tree/253e6c275954cffe13c269a30e2c0e30aad5389d) (git / maven). @nachokk I'm using `
com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: It may not be the actual problem, however, consider using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to init the UI, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for details.

Comment: Yep, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...})` but perhaps more importantly, set the Look & Feel before starting the Swing event thread, in other words before your `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` call.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks. Seems like there are a few things I can improve on this.

Answer (score 4):

Two things jump out at me.

Firstly, you're not initalisig your UI in the EDT, secondly, you're messing with the preferred and minimum sizes of your components.

You are not taking into consideration the font metrics when calculating the size of your components, which seems to be causing issues when it is rendering the content

Start by taking a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

class TextFieldDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("AquaLookAndFeel is not supported on your platform.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
            }

        });
    }

}

class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
//        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
//        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));
//        scrollPane.setViewportView(innerPanel);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(innerPanel);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
//        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 20));

        innerPanel.add(textField);
        pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the L&F be set in the main before the call to `EventQueue.invokeLater(....)`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the explanation and example. I'm using `set*Size()` since the ScrollPane collapses and hides the components inside it -- though that might be a side effect of my weak Swing experience.

Comment: Try placing the scroll pane on a different layout manager, like `BorderLayout`

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");`  would better be `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.  That **will** result in `AquaLookAndFeel` on Mac, and will also work for Windows and *nix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought that too

Comment: @AndrewThompson My actual implementation uses the line of code you suggested, but I specified Aqua in the SSCCE in response to nachokk's comment.